# VBA How to select and offset from application caller address?

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to select the cell that Im using to call my function, which will then be offset. Ex: if C3 is calling the function, it should select cell C3. Then Im going to offset from this cell.

Ive used "Application.Caller.Address" and this gets the cell but when i try offsetting from it ("Application.Caller.Address.Offset(1,0)"), it doesnt work. Now I'm trying to do the same thing using a range.

```
x = Application.Caller.Address.Offset(1, 0)
MsgBox x
```

The MsgBox to see if the right cell is being selected print nothing out. If I take away the Offset part, the MsgBox prints out the calling cell address.

Comment: Why not use `Target` inside the `Worksheet_Change` event ?

Comment: Try `x = Range(Application.Caller.Address).Offset(1, 0)`.

Comment: @ShaiRado I cant use `Target` because I dont know the final cell since its based on the cell calling the function.
@AhmedAU I tried and I just get a blank MsgBox.

Comment: @ShaiRado To clarify a bit further, this function is called multiple times. The target cell is going to be different each time its called since its based on the cell that calls the function.

Comment: @kazisl please read up on the worksheet_change event! The MS Docs explain it quite well. 'Target' is the cell that was changed when the event fires.